# Recursive function that finds all possible paths (of x steps) in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, tuples

I have a dictionary which contains keys and values described as the following:

-each key is a tuple in which the first element is a color and the second element is a number, both as strings;

-each value is a list of one or more tuple, each one has the name of a color as first element and the name of a fruit as second element (again, both as strings).

Example:

```
given_dict = {('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')], 
                ('Yellow', 'three'): [('Green', 'peach')], 
                ('Green', 'seven'): [('Purple', 'lemon')],
                ('Blue', 'three'): [('Purple', 'pineapple')],
                ('Purple', 'three'): [('Red', 'strawberry')], 
                ('Purple', 'seven'): [('White', 'banana'), ('Green', 'dragonfruit')], 
                ('White', 'seven') : [('Green', 'melon')]}
```

Then I have a list of numbers (as strings) which are exactly the numbers contained as the second element in the dictionary keys.
Example:

```
list_of_w = ['one', 'three', 'seven']
```

What I want to do is to create a recursive function that, **without importing libraries**, takes as input a color (as string), a dictionary and a list of numbers as described above, and finds all possible paths which start at given input_color and list_of_w[0] and proceeds with the value corresponding to (input_color, list_of_w[iteration]) untill list_of_w[iteration] == len(list_of_w).

Since I’m not good at explaining (and I’m very sorry for that), I’ll give you an example of what I mean:
Input:

```
given_dict = {('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')], 
                ('Yellow', 'three'): [('Green', 'peach')], 
                ('Green', 'seven'): [('Purple', 'lemon')],
                ('Blue', 'three'): [('Purple', 'pineapple')],
                ('Purple', 'three'): [('Red', 'strawberry')], 
                ('Purple', 'seven'): [('White', 'banana'), ('Green', 'dragonfruit')], 
                ('White', 'seven') : [('Green', 'melon')]}
list_of_w = ['one', 'three', 'seven']
input_color = 'Red'
```

1st path:

```
('Red', 'one') -> ('Blue', 'strawberry')       #input_color = 'Red' | list_of_w[0] = 'one'
('Blue', 'three') -> ('Purple', 'pineapple')   #input_color = 'Blue' | list_of_w[1] = 'three'
('Purple', 'seven') -> ('White', 'banana')     #input_color = 'Purple' | list_of_w[2] = 'seven'

1st path returns ('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White')
```

2nd path:

```
('Red', 'one') -> ('Blue', 'strawberry')          #input_color = 'Red' | list_of_w[0] = 'one'
('Blue', 'three') -> ('Purple', 'pineapple')      #input_color = 'Blue' | list_of_w[1] = 'three'
('Purple', 'seven') -> ('Green', 'dragonfruit')   #input_color = 'Purple' | list_of_w[2] = 'seven'

2nd path returns ('strawberry pineapple dragonfruit', 'Green')
```

3rd path:

```
('Red', 'one') -> ('Yellow', 'banana')           #input_color = 'Red' | list_of_w[0] = 'one'
('Yellow', 'three') -> ('Green', 'peach')        #input_color = 'Yellow' | list_of_w[1] = 'three'
('Green', 'seven') -> ('Purple', 'lemon')        #input_color = 'Green' | list_of_w[2] = 'seven'

3rd path returns ('banana peach lemon', 'Purple')
```

At the end, the function should return a list of all the possible paths as tuples of (string_of_fruits, last_color), in this case:

```
[('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White'), ('strawberry pineapple dragonfruit', 'Green'), (‘banana peach lemon', 'Purple')]
```

First, I initialized some variables to help for some calculations:

```
t = 0               #this will be increased by 1 each time: when (t == l) I may have found a path
l = len(list_of_w)  #to know when I finished the steps 
set_end = set()     #to save values I've already found before
list_of_fruits, result = list(), list()   #same as above
```

Then I wrote the code of my function:

```
def r_find_path(given_dict, t, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end):
    start = (initial_color, list_of_w[t])
    if (start not in given_dict.keys()):  
        return ()
    if (t == l): #arrived at the end
        for end in given_dict[start]:
            list_of_fruits.append(end[1])
            final_color = end[0]
            str_colors = ' '.join(list_of_fruits)
            set_end.add(end)
            result = [(str_colors, final_color)]
            t = 0
            list_of_fruits = list()
            return result[0] + r_find_path(given_dict, t, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end)
    else:   #if(t < l):
        for end in given_dict[start]:
            if (end not in set_end): 
                list_of_fruits.append(end[1])
                initial_color = end[0]
                set_end.add(end)
                return  r_find_path(given_dict, t+1, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end)
```

Expected result should be:

```
[('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White'), ('strawberry pineapple dragonfruit', 'Green'), ('banana peach lemon', 'Purple')]
```

Actual result of my function is:

```
('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White')
```

So it seems that my function has two problems:

1)it doesn't return a list, instead it returns a tuple;

2)it stops at the first path instead of searching for the other two.

Can someone help me to see what I'm doing wrong? It seems I'm having a lot of troubles trying to understand and use recursion properly.

As requested, this is my complete real code:

```
def  function(initial_color, string_of_w):
    given_dict = {('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')], 
                ('Yellow', 'three'): [('Green', 'peach')], 
                ('Green', 'seven'): [('Purple', 'lemon')],
                ('Blue', 'three'): [('Purple', 'pineapple')],
                ('Purple', 'three'): [('Red', 'strawberry')], 
                ('Purple', 'seven'): [('White', 'banana'), ('Green', 'dragonfruit')], 
                ('White', 'seven') : [('Green', 'melon')]}
    t = 0
    list_of_w = string_of_w.split()
    result, list_of_fruits = tuple(), list()
    l = len(list_of_w) - 1
    set_end = set()
    return r_find_path(given_dict, t, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end)
    
def r_find_path(given_dict, t, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end):
    start = (initial_color, list_of_w[t])
    if (start not in given_dict.keys()):  
        return ()
    if (t == l): #arrived at the end
        for end in given_dict[start]:
            list_of_fruits.append(end[1])
            final_color = end[0]
            str_colors = ' '.join(list_of_fruits)
            set_end.add(end)
            result = [(str_colors, final_color)]
            t = 0
            list_of_fruits = list()
            return result[0] + r_find_path(given_dict, t, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end)
    else:   #if(t < l):
        for end in given_dict[start]:
            if (end not in set_end): 
                list_of_fruits.append(end[1])
                initial_color = end[0]
                set_end.add(end)
                return  r_find_path(given_dict, t+1, l, result, list_of_fruits, list_of_w, initial_color, set_end)
```

Calling the function as:

```
function('Red', 'one three seven')
```

should return:

```
('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White')
```

Comment: My guess is that your `return`s are indented one level too much. Since they are inside `for` loops they will stop the loops at their first iterations.

Comment: Even if I move them to the left result doesn't change, unfortunately.

Comment: Please post your real code. When I paste your posting into my IDE it complains about invalid quotes: `(‘Red’, ‘one’)` etc

Comment: I changed quotes from ‘’ to ''. Now it should work properly, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: And the commas: `('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')],` etc ....

Comment: Also an empty `Tuple` is either `()` or `Tuple()` and *not* `(,)`.

Comment: Yeah, Please post your real code. Just in one block instead of making me piece it together. Also you don't show how you call your function.

Comment: Sorry if I made you wait, I had to change all the names of variables in my code because I used different names than the ones I wrote here. Now I  did copy and paste so it should work. Let me know if you're still having troubles.

Comment: No real change. I get: `start = (initial_color, list_of_w[t])
IndexError: list index out of range`  I think you meant: `if (t == l-1): #arrived at the end`

Comment: Ok I created a new file and shared the entire code of it.
Now I tested it personally and it should work as I wrote in the original post. (I put it at the end of the op).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I came up with:

```py
def search(given_dict, list_of_w, input_color, curr_str, ret):
    w = list_of_w[0]
    k = (input_color, w)
    nxt = given_dict[k]
    if len(list_of_w) == 1:
        for k in nxt:
            c, f = k
            final_str = curr_str[:] + [f]
            final_str = ' '.join(final_str)
            ret.append((final_str, c))
    else:
        for k in nxt:
            c, f = k
            nxt_str = curr_str[:] + [f]
            search(given_dict, list_of_w[1:], c, nxt_str, ret)


given_dict = {
    ('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')],
    ('Yellow', 'three'): [('Green', 'peach')],
    ('Green', 'seven'): [('Purple', 'lemon')],
    ('Blue', 'three'): [('Purple', 'pineapple')],
    ('Purple', 'three'): [('Red', 'strawberry')],
    ('Purple', 'seven'): [('White', 'banana'), ('Green', 'dragonfruit')],
    ('White', 'seven'): [('Green', 'melon')]
}
list_of_w = ['one', 'three', 'seven']
initial_color = 'Red'

ret = []
search(given_dict, list_of_w, initial_color, [], ret)
print(ret)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 1):

Simple to construct with a Recursive generator

**Code**

```
def r_find_path(given_dict, list_of_w, initial_color, path=None):
  ' Recursive generator'

  # Path holds the sequence of color, fruit 
  # tuples for a path
  if path is None:
    path = []
    
  # Base case
  # at end of path
  # since list_of_w is empty
  if not list_of_w:
    # Created desired string from path elements
    yield ' '.join(x[1] for x in path), path[-1][0]
    
  else:
    # key with this color and list_of_w value
    start = (initial_color, list_of_w[0])
    
    # Recursively list of values
    for end in given_dict[start]:
        yield from r_find_path(given_dict, list_of_w[1:], end[0], path + [end])
```

**Test**

```
given_dict = {
 ('Red', 'one'): [('Blue', 'strawberry'), ('Yellow', 'banana')],
 ('Yellow', 'three'): [('Green', 'peach')],
 ('Green', 'seven'): [('Purple', 'lemon')],
 ('Blue', 'three'): [('Purple', 'pineapple')],
 ('Purple', 'three'): [('Red', 'strawberry')],
 ('Purple', 'seven'): [('White', 'banana'), ('Green', 'dragonfruit')]}
    
list_of_w = ['one', 'three', 'seven']
input_color = 'Red'
     
# Get list of all solutions     
result = list(r_find_path(given_dict, list_of_w, input_color))       
 # Display solution on each line
print(*result, sep = '\n')
```

**Output**

```
('strawberry pineapple banana', 'White')
('strawberry pineapple dragonfruit', 'Green')
('banana peach lemon', 'Purple')
```

Comment: Can I ask what does: >> if not list_of_w: << mean ? I tried to read something about it but I don't think I understood it.

Comment: `if x:` can be generally translated as `if bool(x) == True:` or `if not x:` becomes `if bool(x) == False`. So `if not list_of_w:` means if  `list_of_w` is empty.